# Retrieve data from Birst using WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, wsdl2apex, birst

I'm trying to retrieve data from Birst using WSDL. I generated the WSDL on Salesforce and got the Apex classses. 
Now I want to use a method called executeQueryInSpace that gets the token response from the login method (which I got successfully).

I'm keep getting the same error:

"Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: getUserForToken: Login token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is invalid or has expired"

```
WS_Birst_wwwBirstCom birstInstance = new WS_Birst_wwwBirstCom();
WS_Birst_wwwBirstCom.CommandWebServiceSoap  soapInstance = new WS_Birst_wwwBirstCom.CommandWebServiceSoap();   
WS_Birst_wwwBirstCom.CommandQueryResult  queryResults = new WS_Birst_wwwBirstCom.CommandQueryResult();
soapInstance.executeQueryInSpace(soapInstance.Login(username, ssopassword), query ,spaceId);
```

Edit:

Birst answered to my case and they claim that I need to support Cookies Management, they also provided an example on C# but I'm not familiar with a similar option in Apex.

Their Answer:

"Birst sessions are tied to the particular server in the load balancer pool and these are stored in Memory. So, very first time when a user does log in request, the load balancer generates a cookie and return it under response header named : Set-Cookie along with login Token response. So, Web services code needs to be programmed in such a way, so that all subsequent Web Service requests contains this Cookie value and ultimately it will help load balancer to take decision that next API call should be redirect to a particular server only. "

Example (C#):

```
// get an instance of the web service
CommandWebService cws = new CommandWebService();
// necessary to support cookie based load balancing
cws.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
// login to the web service
string LoginToken = cws.Login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
// upload the file
uploadData(cws, LoginToken, SPACE_ID, FILENAME);
```

Any thoughts how can I do something like that in Apex?

Comment: Sounds like Birst issue, have you contacted their support?

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for their response

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds primarily like an issue with a third party, rather than with Salesforce.

Comment: Edited the question, may you open it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The login request returns a token as a response but in addition, it puts a pair in a Header map as follow:

```
Map<String, String> outputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
outputHttpHeaders_x.put('Set-Cookie', 'value');
```

Therefore, when one wants to use one of the methods generated by the WSDL he should put into the inputHttpHeaders_x map the value of the 'Set-Cookie' key with a key name 'Cookie' as follow:

```
Map<String, String> inputHttpHeaders_x= new Map<String, String>();
inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Cookie', outputHttpHeaders_x.get('Set-Cookie'));
```